# how does == operator work in java

Tags: java

```
public class StrEqual {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "hi";
        String s2 = new String("hi");

        System.out.println(s1);
        System.out.println(s2);

        if(s1 == s2){
            System.out.println("s1 and s2 are equal");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("s1 and s2 are not equal");
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code s1 and s2 both referring to the string "hi". But why the output of the program is- 's1 and s2 are not equal' ? Thank you

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis how is this a duplicate of that?

Comment: Search for "java compare strings".

Comment: It works exactly like `==`.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
s1.equals(s2);
```

`s1 == s2` compares the object references, not the string contents.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator compares the object reference, i.e., their locations in memory. It's like comparing pointers. To have "deep" equality you need to use the `equals` method.